# gnome-tweak-tool CapsLK and Ctrl button exchange doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to exchange my <kbd>CapsLK</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> buttons. So I configure it in gnome-tweak-tool by choosing `Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock` in `Typing`. But it doesn't work. When I open it from the terminal, I notice the following exception:

```
user1@myhost:~$ gnome-tweak-tool 
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.nautilus.desktop (key computer-icon-visible)

(gnome-tweak-tool:21100): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/user1/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file '/home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.
WARNING : Shell not running
None
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 275, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
```

and with `sudo` it's the same:

```
user1@myhost:~$ sudo gnome-tweak-tool 
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
INFO    : GSettings missing key org.gnome.nautilus.desktop (key computer-icon-visible)
WARNING : Shell not running
None
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 275, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
```

Comment: For what it's worth I'm having the same/similar problem, `gnome-shell --version` `GNOME Shell 3.22.2` on Arch Linux